# Is it possible to add custom comments to the SQL query in JDBI Skife

Tags: jdbi

```sql
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE A=:a")
ModelT func(...)
```

Before the query executes against the DB I would like to preferably do the following:

Attach a comment of the form /* guid=1ndk3 */ to the SQL query:

```
/* guid=1ndk3 */ SELECT foo FROM T1 WHERE A=123;
```

And perform a bit of query rewrite and transform call a function like to_lower() on some columns. Like such:

```
/* guid=1ndk3 */ SELECT to_lower(foo) FROM T1 WHERE A=123;
```

I'm using JDBI v2 "org.skife.jdbi.v2"

What would be a good place for me to accomplish the above?